# reverseOrder() Em java não invertendo

Tags: java, classificação, collection

Estou com um método em java para ordenar um vetor em metodo decrescente, porém quando executo o teste ele me retorna o vetor não ordenado.

Segue o Método:

```
public void sort() {
  int vet[] = this.vetor;
  inverter(vet);
}

private void inverter(int[] vet) {

  Integer[] vet_x = new Integer[vet.length];
  for (int i=0; i < vet.length; i++){
      vet_x[i] = new Integer(vet[i]);
  }
  Arrays.sort(vet_x, Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

O `this.vetor` está sendo gerado pela função `.random()` no arquivo de teste

```
 int[] vetor = geraVetor.random(100);
```

Quando testo a função:

```
@Override
public void sort() {
  int vet[] = this.vetor;
  inverter(vet);
}

private void inverter(int[] vet) {
 Arrays.sort(vet);
}
```

Ele está ordenando certinho em ordem crescente.

A função que imprime o vetor é essa:

```
 public void Ordenacao() {
    GeraVetor geraVetor = new GeraVetor();

    // Crio um novo vetor
    int[] vetor = geraVetor.random(100);

    // Faço uma cópia dele
    int[] experado = Arrays.copyOf(vetor, vetor.length);

    // Ordeno a cópia com uma ordenação do Java
    //Arrays.sort(experado);

    // Teste de Ordenação
    Ordena ordena = new Ordena(vetor);
    ordena.sort();

    System.out.println("Ordenado: " + ordena.toString());
    System.out.println("Experado: " + Arrays.toString(experado));

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(experado, ordena.get());
}
```

Comment: Esse vetor `vet_x` só existe na função `inverter`. Como está a tentar usar o resultado ?

Comment: Vou editar e colocar a função que está mostrando, ela está gerando o vetor, ele está retonando o vetor.

Comment: @Isac Posta isso como resposta. Acho que o Patrick não entendeu o problema aí.

Comment: sim sim, compreendi, ele precisa de um retorno, mas por que se usar Arrays.sort(vet); na mesma maneira ele me da o vetor ordenado?

Comment: Compreendo, como seria o retorno ou como chamaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
private void inverter(int[] vet) {
    Integer[] vet_x = new Integer[vet.length]; // Copia criada, ...
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
        vet_x[i] = vet[i]; // ... preenchida, ...
    }
    Arrays.sort(vet_x, Collections.reverseOrder()); // ... e ordenada.
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
        vet[i] = vet_x[i]; // Copiando de volta para o original.
    }
}
```

Ou seja, depois de ordenar `vet_x`, copie os valores de volta para `vet`.

Note que não precisa usar o `new Integer` (inclusive, fazer isso está *deprecated* desde o Java 9). Com a atribuição direta, o compilador faz o *autoboxing* sozinho.

Comment: "inclusive, fazer isso está deprecated desde o Java 9" Na faculdade ainda usamos a AWT kkkkk, infelismente só uso java la, sou focado em web, wordpress + front.
Acho que vai ter que ser por ai a solução, Obrigado man